Firebase/Flutter: Do I need to keep on checking the app's authentication state, while some app feature relies on the auth(Firebase) uid?
Brief Insight
Hi, good people.
Currently, I am building an app with Flutter and Firebase. The app's database structure is like this >>
>>>> 
Stores (Collection) -> *uid*(firebase generated uid) -> location(Collection) -> *lid*(unique location id) 
-> items (collection) 
-> orders (collection) 
-> transactions (collection) 
-> customer (collection) 
-> ..... 
-> ..... 
-> etc collections 

This is a nested collection structure in Firestore. I feel like this would let me write very less security rules for Firebase-Firestore. I am still not sure how secure this structure will be. But for now, I will just stick with this. [Enlighten me on this security, if I need to be. Thank you]
Now if a user signs in and gets authenticated by Firebase, then Firebase provides Its 'User' class that provides all of the necessary auth data including the uid. So regarding my database design with that uid I can show the user the store and its available locations(list) created by him when he first signed up and went through an onboarding process. *First feature where I would need the uid Then the user decides and selects a store location to operate and access relative data. By selecting a store location he set that location as the current store location and the app saves the user's choice locally. That means now the app also knows the lid(unique location id). Now with both lid and uid users can read, and write items(Inventory), orders-transaction(Pos), etc. So for other features, lid and uid both doc-ids are must.
The Doubt
Now, Consider a scenario, In the app when the user wants all items of the store location, I would create a snapshot(real-time data fetching). So that if some doc of the item collection gets updated or deleted, the user would not need to refresh the screen. Similarly, there would be an orders snapshot and maybe some more. Remember, to access these sub-collections I would need both uid and lid.
Let's say, now a user logs out from the store location [maybe he/she wants to see the condition of other locations of the store like a food franchise owner] or maybe even worse he/she does not like the app anymore and sign out from the app. That means the app now has no uid or lid.
But what about those Firestore real-time snapshots that are still listening and fetching data if changes happen in the relative database? Cause if they were a one-time call I would not have to worry as after the store logs out I would have deleted it from the local storage, so no lid would be available.
So my question is, does the Firebase SDK for the Flutter platform automatically stop the available snapshots that are currently listening to the Firestore collection, when there is no authenticated user available or do I need to keep on checking both the current user’s authentication state and the current store location state and close the snapshots manually from the app?
Sorry if I wrote too much and you had to read all to understand the problem. And Thank you for your time.
I tried to explain my doubt which relates to Firebase integration with Flutter and I expect some experienced Firebase-Flutter developer or Firebase team and Firebase SDK developer for Flutter would solve the doubt for me and if inthe future some other has the same doubt as me they would also get benefitted from the responses. Cause, I could not find one similar to this problem.

The key is Let's say, now a user logs out - when a user logs out, the log out code would log the user out and remove any references/listeners in Firebase that are in place; you have full control over adding and removing listeners. For example, suppose a logged in user wants to know about any changes to an items collection (Swift) let listener = db.collection("items").addSnapshotListener but then later they log out so the app no longer needs updates listener.remove(). Rules can also cause listeners to cancel as they may require an auth'd user. Is there something more?


does the Firebase SDK for the Flutter platform automatically stop the available snapshots that are currently listening to the Firestore collection, when there is no authenticated user available

No, listeners don't stop listening just because a user that was previously signed in becomes signed out.
However, if there was a security rule active that prevented an anonymous user from performing the query that was previously allowed when they were signed in, a listener on that query would stop and generate an error immediately after signout.

Thanks Doug Stevenson for your response.
If you are right, then I think this can be a fatal issue. A user is logged out and yet he is receiving data changes. I know this issue can be solved from front-end by just cancel the stream subscription but if possible this should be solved by the Firebase SDK developers. Right Doug Stevenson?

Since you haven't shown your code or security rules, it's unclear what should happen when the user signs out in your particular case.  I suggest asking a new question, showing all relevant code, and explaining what about that code doesn't work the way you expect. We should be able to reproduce the problem using the information you provide.  If you feel that the behavior is definitely wrong and don't want to post here, then you should contact Firebase support directly with your steps to reproduce.
